# FFmpeg batchfile to compress images JPG JPEGs and keep EXIF (metadata)

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, jpeg, exif

I tried searching everywhere for a possible solution but I really can't find it. Hope someone can help me out here.

I have written a batch file to use FFmpeg to compress and sharpen JPGs in a folder.

```
@ECHO ON
  FOR %%a in (*.jpg) DO (ffmpeg -i "%%a" -q:v 8 -vf unsharp=5:5:1.0:5:5:0.0 "2022 01 22 %%~na".jpg)
PAUSE
```

The new file comes out smaller in size, but is missing all the EXIF information that the original photo has.

I tried to add in the command `-metadata` but apparently it works for MP4 only. I have an existing solution with ImageMagick but I'm hoping to solve this via FFmpeg.

Or is there a way to integrate exiftool into the batch file?

Thank you and I really appreciate any help here.

Comment: You can copy EXIF data forward from one file to another with `exiftool`...

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the new images have the same name with a prefix of "2022 01 22" and are in the same directory?  If so, after running your above command, you could run this exiftool command to copy all the data. `exiftool -overwrite_Original -TagsFromFile "%d2022 01 22 %F" -All:All /path/to/files/`  You do not want to run exiftool in your loop, as exiftool's biggest performance hit is the start up time.  See [Exiftool Common Mistake #3](https://exiftool.org/mistakes.html#M3)

Comment: @StarGeek and Mark, thank you for your replies.

say if, time is not a big issue, can you help me check how i should tweak my batch file code to make it work?

`@ECHO ON


  FOR %%a in (*.jpg) DO (ffmpeg -i "%%a" -q:v 8 -vf unsharp=5:5:1.0:5:5:0.0  "2022 01 22 %%~na".jpg

exiftool -overwrite_Original -TagsFromFile "%%f.pef" -All:All )

PAUSE`

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and add your code in there where it can be formatted and read more easily... comments are not ideal for code. Thanks.